# Is accessing the static value using a global pointer variable is valid?

Tags: c, static, global-variables

Can I access the static variable using the global pointer?

```
//In main.c file
static int c = 20; #Static vairble 
int *ptr = &c; #Global pointer variable
int main(){
  fun();
  printf("%d\n", c);
}

//In sub.c file
extern int *ptr;
void fun(){
  ++*ptr;
}
```

When I tried to access the *ptr global variable using the extern keyword in another file I'm able to access the static variable c and even the changes made on the *ptr is reflecting on c in main.c file

1. Why does "ptr" not loses its global property even after its assigned by a static variable address?
2. Does static and global are stored in two different segments of memory or they both share the same data segment of memory?
3. Can global variables store non-constant values?

Comment: What does `++*ptr` actually do? What indirection is occuring?

Answer (score 4):

`static` is not about laying the object into a portion of memory that cannot be altered /addressed from other translation units. It is just about defining that the object has internal linkage and therefore cannot be grabbed by other translation units through this (internal) name.

But if you somehow get the memory address of an object declared `static` in another translation unit, you may legally access the object.

So your construct is valid.

One might just obey the "static initialization order fiasco" when other translation units draw copies of your `ptr` (probably before this got pointed to `c`).
Consider, for example, what might happen when another translation unit contains at file scope...

```
extern int *ptr;
int *myPtr = ptr;
...
int main() {
   int x = *myPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the linkage of a pointer variable and the linkage of what it *points* to.

The linkage of a pointer does *not* change, regardless of what it points to.

Here the *linkage* of `ptr` is *global* (aka *external*) and the linkage of `c` is `static` (aka *internal*). Neither one changes the linkage of the other.

`static` means that `c` will *not* be *visible* (i.e. available for direct linkage) in another (e.g.) `.c` file. That is, another `.c` could *not* do:

```
int *ptr2 = &c;
```

But, it *could* do:

```
int **ptr3 = &ptr;
```

You could have the reverse:

```
int c = 20;
static int ptr = &c;
```

This is a `static`/internal linkage `ptr` pointing to a global/external linkage `c`.

A program has several memory areas: `.text` for code. `.data` for *initialized* variables (such as `c`) and `.bss` for *unitialized* areas.

Since you *initialize* both `ptr` and `c`, they both end up in `.data`

If you had done:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int c = 20; // Static vairble
int *ptr;

int main(){
    ptr = &c;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, `c` is *initialized* and goes in `.data` but `ptr` is not *initialized* but is *assigned* and goes in the `.bss` segment

All variables [global or not] can have non-constant values. Either by initialization or assignment.

All above variables have global/file *scope*.

Here is another type of scope:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int c = 20; // Static vairble

int main(){
    int *ptr = &c;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `ptr` has *function* scope. It is placed on the stack frame of `main`. It has no linkage to speak of (i.e. it will never show up in the symbol table of the executable).

Comment: Scope is not the issue. Both `c` and `ptr` have *file* scope (which is the term used by the C standard, not global or static). The issue is linkage, which is the process by which the same identifier in different scopes can be made to refer to the same object. `c` has *internal* linkage. `ptr` has *external* linkage.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does "ptr" not loses its global property even after its assigned
>   by a static variable address?

A variable cannot "loose" its scope or storage class, the `static` linkage class specifier determines the *visibility* of the symbol, not where or how it is stored.  It prevents the data being referenced via that *symbol*, it does not prevent pointer references to the same location.  C is a systems level language - as such it does not prevent you from doing pretty much anything that can be done at architecture level.

> Does static and global are stored in two different segments of memory
>   or they both share the same data segment of memory?

No.  The `static` keyword is used in this case to specify *static or or internal linkage*, it is also used (for function-local variables) as a *storage class* specifier, but all variables outside a function have static storage class regardless of internal or external linkage.

That said, initialised static storage data is placed in a different linker section than zero or uninitialised data.  This is to facilitate runtime start-up initialisation.

> Can global variables store non-constant values?

Perhaps that deserves a separate question to explain why you might think otherwise - it seems unrelated to your other questions and a but left-field.  In your own example `ptr` is storing `&c`, but that could be modified at run-time to point elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does "ptr" not loses its global property even after its assigned
>   by a static variable address?

ptr remains global regardless where it points since it is declared global.

> Does static and global are stored in two different segments of memory
>   or they both share the same data segment of memory?

In general they reside in the same data segment.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

> Can global variables store non-constant values?

yes, just like any other variable, thus the name "variable"